# R: request traffic flow data from HERE maps API

Tags: r, here-api, httr

I'm new in working with API using R. I saw another similar post, but it was using API v6 (currently
on maintenance) while the new one is v7. So I post this anyway.

**GOAL**
Get traffic flow data from HERE Maps API v7 based on [this documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/traffic-api/api-reference.html)

**Problem**
I'm using `httr` package to request the traffic flow data with the following code

```
library(httr)
source("config.R")
# Set the API endpoint URL
url <- "https://data.traffic.hereapi.com/v7/flow"

# Set the required query parameters
in_area <- "circle:13.1,-43.1;r=10000"
location_referencing <- c("none", "shape")
min_jam_factor <- 5
max_jam_factor <- 8
functional_classes <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

# Set the headers
headers <- c("apiKey" = here_api_key,
             "X-Request-Id" = "8230d7ad-3f1c-4191-a8dd-f3c42026da89")

# Construct the query string
query_string <- paste0(
  "in=", in_area,
  "&locationReferencing=", paste(location_referencing, collapse = ","),
  "&minJamFactor=", min_jam_factor,
  "&maxJamFactor=", max_jam_factor,
  "&functionalClasses=", paste(functional_classes, collapse = ",")
)

# Create the complete URL with query string
complete_url <- paste0(url, "?", query_string)

# Send the GET request
response <- GET(complete_url, add_headers(headers))
```

It return error `401`

```
$error
[1] "Unauthorized"

$error_description
[1] "No credentials found"
```

**Question**
It's either I write the code for the `apiKey` incorrectly or my API key have no access to traffic flow data.

- I'm sure my API key is correct because I've tried to request `isoline()` data via `hereR` package like in [this code](https://github.com/isaid-hi/bipi.datalab/blob/main/2023.06.24_%234%20Hospital%20Access/hospital_access.R) up to line 33
- I'm sure that traffic flow can be accessed using base plan API as it stated [here](https://www.here.com/get-started/pricing)

So, the most likely thing happened was that I wrote the code wrong, was it?